# Circle-CI - logic statement in commands with two conditions: equals and matches not working well

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have read https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference#logic-statement-examples and I want to had a condition when the tag match a certain pattern to the logic statement:

- when `<< pipeline.git.branch >>` is `master` (current)
  OR
- if `<< pipeline.git.tag >>` is of pattern `/^(patch\/)?v.*/` or `/^hotfix-.*/`

This is our `.circleci.yml` conditions prior any modifications: https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L107-L115

This is what I have tried:

```yaml
      - when:
          condition:
            or:
              - equal: ["master", << pipeline.git.branch >>]
              - matches:
                  pattern: /^(patch\/)?v.*/
                  value: << pipeline.git.tag >>
```

Circle-CI does not run the commands when doing the following:

```bash
git tag patch/v1.199.99
git push origin patch/v1.199.99
```

[image]

Condition doesn't match when `<< pipeline.git.tag >>` is `patch/v1.199.99` and thus doesn't run the pipeline, any clue what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we did : https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/pull/3604#issue-1383526470

We needed to update the workflows to trigger on tags. I don't know why though.

Comment: This is is because, by default, CircleCI builds any branch but doesn't build any tag. To build tags you need to explicitly add a `tags` filter. This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference#tags). I understand that you're assuming the presence of `<< pipeline.git.tag >>` in your logic statement should be enough, but it's not how it works....yet (there's an [open feature request](https://ideas.circleci.com/cloud-feature-requests/p/allow-tag-filtering-at-workflow-level) for that functionality).